# Foreach PHP Loop into Array

Tags: abstract-data-type

I am trying to create an array containing results from an SQL table. But my foreach loop does not appear to be function correctly.

Here is my code:
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        }
        $stmt->close();

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($connected_items as &$value) {
            print_r ($connected_items[$i]);
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $connected_items[$i]);
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $result[] = array(,
                        );
            }
            $stmt->close();

            $i++;
            }
    unset($value);
    )
)
```

It appears to be running the for loop on my print statement and then MySQL statement, using the last connected_items_id, why is that? And why is it not returning the associated values for that id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this [] at line number 6:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $connected_items = array($connected_items_id);
}
```

instead of this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $connected_items[] = array($connected_items_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach ($connected_items as $value) {
 ......................
 ......................
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT name, serial FROM `glpi_monitors` WHERE id =?');
 $stmt->bind_param("i", $value[0]);
 ................................
 ................................
}
```

Also you can use `IN` keyword instead of looping and querying each time.

```
 $sql = "SELECT name, serial FROM `glpi_monitors` WHERE id IN('".implode("','",$connected_items)."'");
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
```

eg :

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
"connected_item_id" => $connected_items[0],
```

instead of

```
"connected_item_id" => $connected_items_id,
```